A question about cross-ratio
Every textbook proves by direct calculation that the cross-ratio [x1, ... x4] is preserved by bilinear transformations y = (ax+b)/(cx+d).
My question is in the opposite direction and it is, partially, historical.
Suppose that we never heard about the cross-ration and don't know its formula.  But we try to map four points  x1, ... x4  to other four points y1,...,y4 by some transformation     y=(ax+b)/(cx+d). It is not necessarily possible for every eight points, x1, ..., y4, so some condition is required.  We hope that the condition will be  [x1, ... x4] = [y1,...,y4]. But how can this be directly deduced?
If we try to solve the system
a x_i + b = y_i( c x_i +d), i=1,...4  for unknow a,b,c,d, the homogeneous system has a nontivial solution iff
det( 1,  x_i, y_i, x_i y_i ) = 0.
This is a nice, symmetric condition but is does not lead to [x1, ... x4] = [y1,...,y4].
So my question is how can we reinvent the cross-ratio and its invariance by straightforward calculation and not by a post-factum verification?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Very briefly.
We start by looking at fewer points, and find that there is exactly one bilinear transformation carrying the triple $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to the triple $(0,1,\infty)$, namely
$$
x\mapsto\frac{x-x_1}{x-x_3}\frac{x_2-x_3}{x_2-x_1}.
$$
Now if we look at quadruples $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ we see that we can map this to a quadruple $(0,1,\infty,\lambda)$ if and only if $\lambda=\frac{x_4-x_1}{x_4-x_3}\frac{x_2-x_3}{x_2-x_1}$.
Now given two quadruples $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$ we can pass from one to the other if and only if we can carry each to the same $(0,1,\infty,\lambda)$; that is if they have the same cross-ratio.

Thank you!    Is there any brute force approach to prove the same without using (0,1,∞,λ)?    I try to find the most basic/primitive way to get the cross-ratio.

I don't think brute force is the way to go. I reckon that this is the most natural way to define cross-ratio. Since the bilinear transformations form a group it seems to me to be natural and well within the spirit of 19cent maths to pass from an arbitrary triple to the natural coordinate one $(o,\infty,1)$ [in some order]. In more modern language the group is "sharply $3$-transitive".

But if you really want to suppress the reference to $0,1,\infty$ you just have to notice that the transformation carrying $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ is the bilinear mapping $x\mapsto y$ where $y$ is determined by the equation $\frac{x-x_1}{x-x_3}\frac{x_2-x_3}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{y-y_1}{y-y_3}\frac{y_2-y_3}{y_2-y_1}$; if now  $x_4\mapsto y_4$ you'll get the equality of cross-ratios.
